# Dúvidas estrutura de um crud no Android

Tags: java, android, crud

Tenho as seguintes as classes: Cliente, ClienteDAO e DAO.

No modelo Cliente eu tenho os atributos e os gets/sets.

Na ClienteDAO eu tenho os métodos salvar(), alterar(), … ou seja, o crud. Essa classe monta uma string com os parâmetros e envia para a DAO.

Na DAO ela é uma classe que tem os métodos da biblioteca Volley que faz as conexões com o web service. Após o envio ele recebe um JSON como resposta e envia para o ClienteDAO que trata este JSON transformando em um objeto usando a biblioteca Gson e então retorna o objeto para a classe que solicitou.

A classe DAO é uma classe que é usada por todas as classes que necessitam de uma conexão com webserver.

Essa lógica está correta? Pois me ocorre o seguinte problema:

Suponhamos que eu faça uma chamada para a classe ClienteDAO que o seu retorno será incluído o nome do usuário em um TextView. Acontece que a aplicação ficará travada até obter esse retorno.

Como posso resolver isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: A aplicação não ficará "travada", as requisições `http`, não podem ser mais feitas na `thread` principal... Você pode colocar um texto no TextView de *Carregando*, ou criar um `progressDialog`, para informar que está indo buscar os dados..

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário! Então a estrutura que criei esta correta?

Comment: Só um detalhe, o Pattern  DAO  é um padrão para banco de dados, só achei estranho a classe DAO para acessar o webservice.. talvez ficará um pouco confuso,

Comment: Como você faria?

Comment: Abandone esse padrão para mexer com webservice.
Cria uma classe (classe x) que tenha os métodos do crud e esse métodos recebem o objeto por parametro.
Aí voce cria uma asynctask, que é quando voce roda alguma tarefa em segundo plano....Dentro da asynctask voce programa para a classe x fazer a requisição no webservice...Na activity, voce chama a async task que ela requisitará o webservice em segundo plano. assim o aplicativo não ficará travado...

Comment: Eu simplificaria as coisas como @Mr_Anderson falou. Criaria objetos simples (POJO - plain old java objects) e usaria uma biblioteca de REST que automatize a chamada e desserialização do json, tais como Retrofit (http://square.github.io/retrofit/), minha predileta, ou spring (https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-android/). Com retrofit você nem precisa criar uma classe para ser o seu "DAO", no caso o seu "Client Rest", pois ela já cria pra você. Só precisa consumir o código mesmo